# Regex Lazy mode doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following string:

```
FFSMQWUNUPZRJMTHACFELGHDZEJWFDWVPYOZEVEJKQWHQAHOCIYWGVLPSHFESCGEUCJGYLGDWPIWIDWZZXRUFXERABQJOXZALQOCSAYBRHXQQGUDADYSORTYZQPWGMBLNAQOFODSNXSZFURUNPMZGHTA
```

I'm trying to match every substring that contains `CABDA` with the following regex:

```
C.*?A.*?B.*?D.*?A
```

The only thing I find then is

```
CFELGHDZEJWFDWVPYOZEVEJKQWHQAHOCIYWGVLPSHFESCGEUCJGYLGDWPIWIDWZZXRUFXERABQJOXZALQOCSAYBRHXQQGUDA
```

Which in itself is not wrong - but I should be finding `CSAYBRHXQQGUDA`

What am I missing?

You can test it [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/pW6yD2/1) if you'd like

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is how regexes are supposed to work. They look for the *first* match, not the *shortest*. Laziness does not alter that behavior, it simply will aim to match the shortest *of all strings that start there*.

Comment: @CommuSoft I tried with groups as well. Shouldn't I be getting all matches then?

Comment: @Nilzone- you will if you use `lookahead`.

Comment: @Nilzone-, matching would "consume" the character at that position. That is why you don't get all substrings if they intersect with one another. Each position can be used in only one match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?=(C.*?A.*?B.*?D.*?A))
```

Put your expression inside `lookahead` to get all matches.See demo

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/46

If you want to find only the shortest you can use

```
C(?:(?!C|A|B|D).)*A(?:(?!C|A|B|D).)*B(?:(?!C|A|B|D).)*D(?:(?!C|A|B|D).)*A
```

Comment: Your regex is terrible. `(?:(?!C|A|B|D).)*` can be rewritten as `[^CABD]*`.

Comment: @nhahtdh I guessed OP must be having some complex problem...like some strings instead of simple ABCD

Comment: I forgot to mention this earlier - the second regex is also wrong for input such as CAADBA. It only happens to work with the input in the question.

Answer (score 2):

A lazy quantifier doesn't mean that it would try to match the smallest substring possible. It just means that it would try to match as little characters as it can and backtrack towards more characters, as opposed to match as many characters as it can and backtrack towards less.

Finding the position remains the same - the first one from left to right. For example:

```
x+?y
```

when matched against:

```
xxxy
```

will still match `xxxy` and not just `xy` since it was able to start from the first `x` and backtrack towards more `x`es.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this negation class based regex:

```
/C[^C]*?A[^A]*?B[^B]*?D[^D]*?A/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bQ9jP9/1)

This finds `CSAYBRHXQQGUDA` in your given input.